# Is this US passport damaged?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, passports

Seems like used hand sanitizing wipes in my pocket melted the front cover of my passport that was also in my pocket.

[image]

Inside of the passport is fine. Just the cover.

Comment: We don't do opinions here; this site looks for questions that have declarative and authoritative answers. Take the [Tour](https://travel.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn more. I voted to close.

Comment: Doesn't matter what the users here think. Contact your passport-issuing authority or embassy/consulate.

Comment: Questions about passport damage are common here. With a photo, as this one is, they are acceptable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably best to contact your local passport-issuing authority or your nearest Embassy or Consulate. Since the passport in question is US, you can find the official list of Embassies/Consulates/Diplomatic Missions from [US Embassy.gov](https://www.usembassy.gov/).

Give them a call, and they'll be more than happy to help you!